# Prevent Laravel auth/token to be accessed publicly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.6

According to our application requirement I created a custom function to provide tokens to our application users. This function is working correctly as per our requirement. But I need to restrict users to access laravel default oauth/token. If we are providing our own functions to provide tokens then users must not be able to access laravel default method of accessing tokens. How can I be able to do that.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **passport**.

You Could make some middle-ware , and register it in the `app/Http/Kernel.php` to prevent access to this

And in `App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider` change
 `\Passport::routes();` to

```
\Passport::routes(null,[
    'middleware'=>'the-middleware-you-created',
]);
```

Comment: This is not the answer to my question. Adding a middleware can reduce my code for different endpoints but it will not solve my exact problem. I just want that users should not be able to access larvael's default auth/token method directly to access token. Currently oauth/token provides token when called from client.

Comment: Sorry , Buy can you Explain a little bit more what are you trying to achive